# rosbag play speed

Tags: ros, rosbag, play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All
I am using rosbag play --clock myrecod.bag to play file and subscribe these three topics:
"/camera/rgb/image_color", "/camera/depth/image", "/camera/depth/camera_info"
and I want to process each frame of these topics by fovis (http://code.google.com/p/fovis/).my recording file is 20 fps and I have time-consuming calculation on each frame of data. There for I only able to subscribe 4 fps of my recordings.

How can I slow down the play back speed of my recordings file  in order to get all frames?

Thanks in Advance
Ramin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46472/rosbag-play--speed/) by [raminzohouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/3438/raminzohouri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the `-r` or `--rate` parameter of [rosbag play](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#play).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raminzohouri](https://answers.ros.org/users/3438/raminzohouri/) on 2012-10-22**:
Thank you Thomas
I set rate value to 0.1 and now its working well and I am able to capture all the frames.